# Can we define limited access to SharePoint to a group of users only and/or to a group of sites only

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, administration, accesscontrol

Currently inside the SharePoint Online admin center, we can define a global setting to define limited access for all users and for all sites when accessed using unmanaged devices.

[image]

but can this be more flexible? so we define that only certain sites and only certain users will have limited access when accessed from unmanaged devices? so this setting will not affect all users and all sites?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can, by using [sensitivity labels](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/compliance/sensitivity-labels?view=o365-worldwide) in Microsoft 365. When that is done you can turn to PowerShell and run this as an example:

```
Set-SPOSite -Identity https://<SharePoint online URL>/sites/<name of site or OneDrive account> -ConditionalAccessPolicy AllowLimitedAccess
```

However, for specific users that's not an option. You can only do this for all users on a specific site. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/control-access-from-unmanaged-devices#block-or-limit-access-to-a-specific-sharepoint-site-or-onedrive

Comment: thanks for the great reply